# Can you see the figure?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

**What 4-word phrase does the grid represents?**

---

```
                    ISITMINEORI
                    ITINAMTRYIN        
                    RISHELAREMO        
                    ONGESTOFMIC        
                    SYKINDLOCAB
                    TEDINAFRICA
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm guessing the 4-word phrase is

> [**Great Pyramid of Giza.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Pyramid_of_Giza)

This is because

> Within the grid of letters, in a pyramid shape, is the phrase I AM THE LARGEST OF MY KIND LOCATED IN AFRICA.
>
>  [image: clue shown]

> This clue and the fact that it was hidden in a pyramid shape suggests that we are looking for the largest/tallest pyramid in the world, which must satisfy the fact that it is located in Africa. Excluding modern pyramids, we see in the link above that the tallest one is the Great Pyramid of Giza, which is indeed in Africa (specifically Egypt).